# How can I use the result of a method in two different sections of the HTML code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component in Vue.js that prettifies some content. In essence, I clean it in a method and print its result in a HTML tag:

```
<template>
  ....
  <div v-for="(value) in mydata">
    <h2>{{ prettifyMyNumber(value) }}</h2>
  </div>
  ...
</template>
```

Where the code is something like this:

```
export default {
    // ...
    methods: {
        prettifyMyNumber(num) {
            // some calculations
            return 23;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the number and return the integer and float part separately, so that I can then print each part in a different block. I am changing the method so it is something like this:

```
    methods: {
        prettifyMyNumber(num) {
            // some calculations
            return [numValue, floatValue];
        }
    }
```

so I would like my view to get the result of `prettifyMyNumber(value)` and use each part in a different section.

The trivial alternative is to say:

```
<template>
  ....
  <div v-for="(value) in mydata">
    <h2>{{ prettifyMyNumber(value)[0] }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ prettifyMyNumber(value)[1] }}</h3>
  </div>
  ...
</template>
```

but it implies calling the method twice. Is there a way to store the value somewhere and then provide the values to both `h2` and `h3`?

Comment: Why not just `map` `mydata` by returning an object or array before passing it to the template and do the calculations there?

Comment: Just move the function call out of the template.

Comment: @Ouroborus excellent, using `set` was a key part to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to actually produce an entirely new array from `mydata` using a computed property, and then use that computed property in your `v-for` binding:

```
export default {
    computed: {
        // Computed prop iterates through `mydata` and returns an array of tuples
        prettifiedNumbers() {
            return this.mydata.map(datum => this.prettifyMyNumber(datum.value))
        }
    }
    methods: {
        prettifyMyNumber(num) {
            // some calculations
            return [numValue, floatValue];
        }
    }
}

<template>
  ....
  <div v-for="entry in prettifiedNumbers">
    <h2>{{ entry[0] }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ entry[1] }}</h3>
  </div>
  ...
</template>
```

If you still want to preserve the data in `mydata`, you can simply add a new property to the object instead:

```
export default {
    computed: {
        myTransformedData()) {
            return this.mydata.map(datum => {
                // Add `prettifiedNumbers` tuple as a new key-value pair
                datum.prettifiedNumbers = this.prettifyMyNumber[datum.value];
                
                return datum;
            });
        }
    }
    methods: {
        prettifyMyNumber(num) {
            // some calculations
            return [numValue, floatValue];
        }
    }
}

<template>
  ....
  <div v-for="entry in myTransformedData">
    <h2>{{ entry.prettifiedNumbers[0] }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ entry.prettifiedNumbers[1] }}</h3>
  </div>
  ...
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do it by

```
<template v-for="value in mydata" >
   <div v-for="(num,index) in [prettifyMyNumber(value)]" :key="index">
      {{num[0]}}
      {{num[1]}}
  </div>
</template>
```

the template here is not the main template its inner template (and if all you have its just this template so my advice is to use functional component instead)

Answer (score -1):

Why not use computed property since it caches data.

```
computed: {
    firstPart() {
        return prettifyMyNumber(value)[0];
    },
    secondPart() {
        return prettifyMyNumber(value)[1];
    }
}
```